# Nodemailer sending email with empty body

Tags: javascript, node.js, pug, nodemailer

I'm using nodemailer with npm package email-templates. I'm not getting email. Template is working when i set preview:true. Getting error on console **Error: No recipients defined**.Why this error coming? Tried many things but nodemailer is sending empty email every time. Hope you understand my issue.

Headers:

```
from:   testing@gmail.com
to: my_email@gmail.com
date:   Jan 3, 2020, 3:23 PM
subject:    New password request
mailed-by:  gmail.com
signed-by:  gmail.com
security:    Standard encryption (TLS) Learn more
```

Error:

```
Error: No recipients defined
    at SMTPConnection._formatError (E:\testing\node_modules\nodemailer\lib\smtp-connection\index.js:784:19)
    at SMTPConnection._setEnvelope (E:\testing\node_modules\nodemailer\lib\smtp-connection\index.js:995:34)
    at SMTPConnection.send (E:\testing\node_modules\nodemailer\lib\smtp-connection\index.js:615:14)
    at sendMessage (E:\testing\node_modules\nodemailer\lib\smtp-transport\index.js:227:28)
    at E:\testing\node_modules\nodemailer\lib\smtp-transport\index.js:285:25
    at SMTPConnection._actionAUTHComplete (E:\testing\node_modules\nodemailer\lib\smtp-connection\index.js:1537:9)
    at SMTPConnection.<anonymous> (E:\testing\node_modules\nodemailer\lib\smtp-connection\index.js:550:26)
    at SMTPConnection._processResponse (E:\testing\node_modules\nodemailer\lib\smtp-connection\index.js:942:20)
    at SMTPConnection._onData (E:\testing\node_modules\nodemailer\lib\smtp-connection\index.js:749:14)
    at TLSSocket.SMTPConnection._onSocketData (E:\testing\node_modules\nodemailer\lib\smtp-connection\index.js:195:44)
    at TLSSocket.emit (events.js:210:5)
    at addChunk (_stream_readable.js:309:12)
    at readableAddChunk (_stream_readable.js:290:11)
    at TLSSocket.Readable.push (_stream_readable.js:224:10)
    at TLSWrap.onStreamRead (internal/stream_base_commons.js:182:23) {
  code: 'EENVELOPE',
  command: 'API'
}
```

My directory structure:

```
├── app.js
└── emails
    └── forget-password
        ├── html.pug
        ├── subject.pug
```

Node mailer with template:

```
const nodemailer = require('nodemailer');
var generator = require('generate-password');

const Email = require('email-templates');

exports.sendNodeForgotPasswordMail = function (email, GeneratePassword) {
    var transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
        host: 'smtp.gmail.com',
        port: 587,
        secure: false,
        auth: {
            user: 'my_email',
            pass: 'my_password'
        },
        tls: {
            rejectUnauthorized: false
        }

    });

    const emailVar = new Email({
        message: {
            from: 'testing@gmail.com'
        },
        preview: true,
        send: true,
        transport: {
            jsonTransport: true
        }
    });

    emailVar.send({
        template: 'forget-password',
        message: {
            to: email
        },
        locals: {
            password: GeneratePassword
        }
    }) .then(res => {
        console.log('res.originalMessage', res.originalMessage)
    }).catch(console.error);


    return transporter.sendMail(emailVar, function (err, info) {
        if (err)
            console.log(err);
        else
            console.log(info);
    });
};
```

Html.pug:

```
p Your new password is: #{password}
```

subject.pug

```
= `Password reset request`
```

Comment: I strongly suspect you need `secure: true,` if you want to connect to gmail SMTP servers.

Comment: @O.Jones I'm already connected with gmail.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the structure of your project is not quite right. There should be a directory for each template that you want to create, and within each of those directories you should have a `subject.pug` file, a `text.pug` file (for text only) and an `html.pug` file (for HTML).

The example directory structure in the documentation for a template named `mars` looks like this:

```
.
├── app.js
└── emails
    └── mars
        ├── html.pug
        ├── text.pug
        └── subject.pug
```

For debugging, you can use the DEBUG environment flag:

```
DEBUG=email-templates node app.js
```

You can also take a look at the `originalMessage` in the response object from `emailVar.send()` like this:

```js
emailVar.send({
  ...
  })
  .then(res => {
    console.log('res.originalMessage', res.originalMessage)
  })
  .catch(console.error);
```

You can see more advanced configurations here: https://www.npmjs.com/package/email-templates

Comment: What is printed to the console when you attempt to send an email? Also, did you set the DEBUG environment variable?

Comment: It seems the value of `email` is not being set. Can you post the email you are receiving in your inbox? With headers (scrubbed, of course)

Comment: I've added headers in my question.

Comment: A couple of things: 1) I was expecting to see many more headers from the email original (e.g. Content-Type), 2) the subject listed in your headers "New password request" is different than the subject in your subject.pug ("Password reset request")...are you sure these headers are from the correct email? 3) I just noticed your file `Html.pug` is capitalized and I think it needs to be all lowercase.